# How to overwrite Boostrap's nav bar inline search bar width?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make the search bar in a nav bar from Bootstrap longer.

I'm using this example from the [Bootstrap site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#forms) but I want the search bar to be long enough so it can show the placeholder. Still, I can't seem to find a way to make it longer.

I'm new to HTML/CSS/JS/Bootstrap, so I'd appreciate if you can explain me how to achieve that and how the solution works. Thanks!:D

Reference image:
[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="This is a quite long placeholder">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to add a class to the input, in this case (large-input):

```
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2 large-input" type="search" placeholder="This is a quite long placeholder">
```

And using CSS, you can add a min-width attribute:

```
.large-input{
  min-width: 300px; /*You can add the size you want here*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to accomplish this. Here's the first one I saw.

1. Remove the `mr-auto` (margin-right: auto) class from the list element. That had been pushing the input to the right, but it was troublesome here.
2. Add `ml-auto` to the input. This pushes the input to the right without causing other issues.
3. Add `flex-fill` to both the form and the input to make them stretch.
4. Add a custom class for a custom max width to the input. Optionally wrap it in a media query to let it full width for mobile.

[Bootstrap Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors)

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .header-search-input {
    max-width: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 flex-fill">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 ml-auto flex-fill header-search-input" type="search" placeholder="This is a quite long placeholder">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```